# How to Create ONE list which can have a string or image as an item in the list

Tags: android, image, listview, text, listadapter

I want to create a journal that appears as a list in a `ListView`. The list should be able to have a text entry or an image for each row. Now, I have these entries (text and image) in a database. I just want to know how to create a list adapter which can have these entries. From the examples I have seen, the list adapters all have only one data type. I want my adapter to have data type `image` or `text`. Please Help! Been searching for 3 hours now.

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

To show images in some listItems and text in others, declare both an ImageView and a TextView in the listitem xml, and hide/show one of them with View.setVisibility(...), where you bind the content. For examples of multiple children in a listItem, refer to other Nik's answer